# Renaming files with python in specific format

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm trying to rename files in one folder, in the pattern 0001, 0002, 0010, 0100 etc. I'm very very new to python, so sorry for asking something so basic.

I've searched around, and most of the code I come across will rename files (not how I want it) or strip out certain characters. I've also come across code which uses extra modules (glob) which only take me further down the rabbit hole. Most of what I see just makes my head spin; at the moment my skills don't go beyond simple functions, if, when, for, while statements and so on.

I've cobbled together some code, that I (somewhat) understand, but it doesn't work.

```
import os

dir = os.listdir("D:\\temp\\Wallpapers")

i = 0

for item in dir:
    dst ="000" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    src = item
    dst = item + dst 

    # rename() function will 
    # rename all the files 
    os.rename(src, dst) 
    i += 1
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.rename(src, dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '00-Pyatna.jpg' -> '0000.jpg'
```

Comment: did you try `dir = os.listdir("D:/temp/Wallpapers")`

Comment: os.rename is looking for files in it's current working directly, which is likely the directory of your .py file, you need to specify full path to file instead of just filename. Add dirname="D:\\temp..." To both src and dst (and don't forget the \ in the middle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you probably are not in the proper directory and you are trying to find those files in the directory you are located right now. You should do it using absolute paths. See the following code

```
import os

base_path = "D:/temp/Wallpapers"
files = os.listdir(base_path)


for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    dst = os.path.join(base_path, "{0:04d}.jpg".format(i))
    src = os.path.join(base_path, fp) 
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: Thanks! Please consider upvoting my post if you think it was clear :D

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Just a follow-up question. How would I go about excluding the file extensions from the rename?

Comment: Easy :D! You would have to filter the files list. For example, considering you want to exclude pdfs, I would add a line after the line where I define `files` like this: `files = [x for x in files if not x.lower().endswith("pdf")]`

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I've come across such an implementation, ie. assigning a variable and then assigning it. I've learnt quite a few things today, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can retrieve the maximum number already present in your folder with the following function

```
import re
def max_counter_in_files(folder):
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    maxnum = '0'
    if files:
        maxnum = max([max(re.findall("[\d]+", file)) for file in files])
    return maxnum
```

For example, if your folder contains the files

```
file001.txt
file002.txt
file003.txt
```

then `max_counter_in_files('path/to/your/files')` would return `3`.

Secondly, you can use that function to increment your next filename when adding new files. for example,

```
counter = int(self.max_counter_in_files(dest_path))
filename = f"filename{counter+1:04d}.txt"
```

`filename` would then be `"filename0004.txt"`.